# How to select maximum of all values in datetime field but less or equal to other datetime value?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my tables, it's pretty lame but don't pay attention :

```
 CREATE TABLE items (
 item_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 item_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 item_cat int(11) NOT NULL,
 item_desc text DEFAULT NULL,
 item_cost decimal(10, 0) DEFAULT NULL,
 item_image varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 item_brand varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 item_active int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)

CREATE TABLE prices (
price_id decimal(10, 0) NOT NULL,
price_date datetime NOT NULL,
price decimal(10, 0) DEFAULT NULL,
fake int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (fake)
)

CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_fam varchar(255) NOT NULL,
order_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
order_otc varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
order_phone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
order_email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
order_delivery int(11) NOT NULL,
order_payment int(11) NOT NULL,
order_comment varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
order_status int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
order_adress varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
order_user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
order_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
)

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query = 'SELECT *                                                 
 FROM                                               
prices                                                  
 WHERE                                              
price_date IN (SELECT MAX(price_date) FROM prices WHERE price_id= ' . $it . ')';
```

price_id references to item_id

But here's the deal.

Now I want the application to show item's price at the moment of the order (order_date) and I have a history of prices in "prices" like this:

2013-04-19 10:13:51 $2000

2013-03-21 11:15:56 $3000

2013-02-03 10:45:22     $1400

So until now i just selected max date from that table. How would you suggest me to modify the query?
(Maximum datetime of the "prices" but less or equal to order_date)

EDIT:
I want to SELECT price value (price field) that was active at the moment of the order (order_date field).
So if order_date = 2013-03-29 11:15:56 then price = $3000 not $2000 and not $1400

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output. It's not clear from your description what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query could be improved:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prices                                                  
ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If I were you I would also add a field "price_id" into orders table and that would be the hook for your select whenever you need to bring back pre price when the order was made:

```
SELECT o.*, p.price
FROM orders o                                              
INNER JOIN prices p ON (o.price_id = p.price_id);
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.* FROM                                               
prices  p1 
inner join prices p2 on p1.price_date < p2.price_date  
WHERE 
p2.price_date = 'some date' 
ORDER BY p1.price DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query = 'SELECT *
FROM
     prices
    WHERE
    price_id = ' . $it . ' AND price_date <= "' . $date . '" ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT  1';
```

I don't really need LIMIT because i'm not running any loop through the array, it's just for the sake of clarity